# Compute Arithmetic Sum to Communicate with Machine Over Serial

Tags: c++, checksum

I am communicating with a machine over serial. Part of the protocol communication spec states that the control sum is an "arithmetic sum of bytes from <'PS'> (included), <'data'> to <'CS'>"

The packet messages are structured as follows:

<'PS'><'data'><'CS'>, where:

*<'PS'> - Packet Size*

Length: 1

Value: 0x02 to 0x63

Max packet length is 99 bytes

*<'data'> - Data*

Length: 1...90 bytes

Value: 0x00 - 0xFF

The length of the data part depends on the command.

*<'CS'> - Check Sum*

Length - 1 byte

Value: 0x00 - 0xFF

Example:

ACK Packet: 0x02 0x01 **0x03** where 0x03 is the checksum.

**So how do I compute the checksum for these bytes in C++?**

Comment: "Arithmetic sum" is a tautology. You can also just call it "sum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the checksum is a simple sum, modulo 256.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int j = 0;  j < number_of_bytes_in_message;  ++j)
   sum += message [j];

sum %= 256;  // or, if you prefer  sum &= 255;
```

Comment: accepted but I ended up using `unsigned char cs = 0;` so if it is greater than 255, it resets to 0

Comment: Don't forget to include the length in the checksum.  sum = number_of_bytes_in_message.

Comment: The examples don't show what happens for an 8-bit wrap around sum.  Some checksum algorithms add the high byte in too [`sum = (sum & 255)  +  (sum >> 8)`].  That's why I didn't truncate during the summation.

Comment: @wallyk: gotcha.. It does not seem to work that way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use an unsigned 8-bit type (uint8_t or unsigned char) as an accumulator, add each byte to it as you generate the packet, then send it as the checksum byte.  Exactly how depends on how you intend to construct the packets.

Comment: I am using char buff[256] and setting each byte to a hexadecimal value.